# Скорость выполнения python and c

Tags: python, c, c++

Всем привет!

Есть два кода один на С:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
  {
   FILE *fp;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   fp = fopen("vlan112.txt", "r");

   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
       printf("%s", line);
   }

}
```

Время выполнения:
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s

На python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

for k in open("vlan112.txt"):
   print k.rstrip()
```

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.012s

Текст в файле:

```
 10.1.12.64      00:25:22:2b:fa:98       vlan112 rjabchevskii
```

Почему такая большая разница в скорости? В текстовом файле 72 строки всего.

Comment: Это наверно модно везде добавлять C++ ?

Comment: Вдруг кто из С++ проснётся)

Comment: И как на практике golang? Понятно что где-то мелкие вещи делал все получалась. Много что написано, а на самом деле истина в практике)

Answer (score 9):

Почти все время выполнения данной программы на Питоне занимает загрузка интерпретатора.

Comment: Получается у всех языков интерпритируемых такая беда?

Comment: Наверное, да. И это еще не самое страшное.

Comment: Если можно с детальным пояснением, очень интересно.

Comment: Есть небольшие проекты написанные на python, чувствую что в скором будущем нужно переписывать, нагрузка растет.

Comment: А что тут добавить? Программы на интерпретируемых языках всегда выполняются медленнее и занимают больше памяти. Используются эти языки из-за удобства и легкости программирования. Но если нужна настоящая скорость, нужно смотреть в сторону компилируемых языков.

Comment: Интересно как в golang обстоят дела в реалях.

Comment: @mikillskegg 

     Но если нужна настоящая скорость, нужно смотреть в сторону компилируемых языков.

Xavier Leroy, "Project Zinc", утверждает, что потери на интерпретацию байт-кода -- десятки процентов. Но не разы.

Comment: Ну так то байт-код, а не чистые языки

Comment: Ну да, та же Джава вроде бы сейчас весьма быстрой стала.

Comment: > что потери на интерпретацию байт-кода -- десятки процентов. 

а виртуальную машину загрузить, а GC запустить:), мир остановить.

Comment: @KoVadim ну GC -- это к байт-коду перпендикулярно. А бинарник загрузить, вместе с dll'ками?

Comment: @mikillskegg 

     Ну так то байт-код, а не чистые интерпретируемые язык

А какие языки сейчас чистые интерпретируемые? Lua? Я просто не в курсе, но у питона .pyc -- результат трансляции...

Answer (score 8):

На таких коротких примерах измерять скорость работы программ вообще нельзя.

Дело в том, что реально система подсчитывает количество прерываний исполняющегося  процесса при возникновении аппаратного прерывания от системного таймера (а это обычно в Linux 100, а в Windows (если не путаю) 1000 раз в секунду) отдельно для режима ядра и режима пользователя.
И вообще, все время в системе (как для статистики, так и для планирования) меряется именно в тиках таймера (сейчас 0.01 сек в Linux).

При окончании процесса, если эти счетчики в нуле, идут не совсем честные рассчеты (для чего, если често, не знаю), результаты возвращаются в `struct rusage` в `wait3()`/`wait4()`, откуда их и берет команда `time`.

Если Вы запустите свои примеры десяток раз, то скорее всего увидите, что разброс времени работы довольно большой.

И даже если мерять время не командой `time`, а вызывая, например `gettimeofday()` (возвращает секунды и микросекунды) или `clock_gettime()` (секунды и наносекунды) в начале и конце участка кода, то IMHO верить измерениям, короче 1 миллисекунды нельзя.

Желающие могут поэкспериментировать с повторяемостью замеров сами.

Comment: Это все правильно, но ТС столкнулся с конкретным явлением и просит его объяснения.

Comment: Вот я и объясняю, как

     real 0m0.003s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.004s

(видите, sys > real !!!) 

такое следует понимать.

Comment: @avp, при чем тут это? Человек спрашивает, почему аналогичная программа на Си и на Питоне имеет такую разницу в скорости.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну, то есть как, при чем?

Используя измерительный инструмент (`time`), человек должен представлять, что и с какой точностью он может измерять.

Судя по вопросу, этого он не знает.

Answer (score 4):

Так вообще нельзя мерять.

В реальном приложении запуск интерпретатора происходит 1 раз, если это не регулярно запускаемый скрипт. Поэтому временем запуска интерпретатора можно пренебречь. Что там эти пять секунд, если программа работает хотя бы полчаса.

Чтобы получить более реальные цифры, а не мифические 0.000 сек необходимо завернуть код программы в большой цикл (например, 1000 раз).

Но при этом следует подумать - какое влияние на замеры окажет особенность работы операционной системы (открытие файла довольно значительно по времени как правило) и кэширования диска.

В данном конкретном случае нельзя говорить об плохой работе интерпретируемого языка программирования. Так как тут большая часть времени (если исключить запуск интерпретатора) - это ввод-вывод. Который от конкретного языка мало зависит.

И еще - в данном конкретном примере налицо зависимость от кэша диска. А погрешности, вносимые диском, столь велики, что делать "гениальные" выводы про производительность просто глупо.

Интерпретируемые языки и должны быть медленнее компилируемых, но на реальных задачах разница не обязательно столь велика, как в данном случае. Например, на типичной задаче - при выполнении запросов к базе данных - у компилируемого не будет преимущества.

Именно поэтому, что в реальности скорость работы программы не всегда зависит от языка, интерпретируемые языки - широко используются в том числе и на нагруженных проектах (например, сервисы Гугля в значительной степени реализованы на Python)

Правильным сравнением будет сравнение БЕЗ использования ВВОДА-ВЫВОДА. Тогда мы исключаем факторы, не зависящие от языка программирования. То есть - реализуйте алгоритм, крутящийся внутри, без чтения файлов и рисования графиков. Например, решето Эратосфена.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/133037/

http://easy-coding.blogspot.ru/2010/03/go-c-c.html

Comment: @Softa, Вам не кажется совет

    Правильным сравнением будет сравнение БЕЗ использования ВВОДА-ВЫВОДА.

для программы, которая сравнивает **скорость печати файла**, несколько странным?

Comment: > Так как тут большая часть времени (если исключить запуск интерпретатора) - это ввод-вывод. Который от конкретного языка мало зависит.

От языка оно то не зависит, от рантайма языка - ещё как.

А вот по поводу кеша - это серьезное замечание. Файл мог закешироваться и сильно повлиять на результат.

Comment: Кстати, код самого интерпретатора и .so тоже кэшируется. Это тоже надо иметь в виду при измерениях.

Comment: To AVP: Для скорости чтения из файла на экран? Не смешите меня вовсе. Скорость вывода зависит (в разы и десятки и сотни раз) даже от того, каков размер окна и перекрывают ли его другие окна (в частности, нужно ли прокручивать вывод в окне или по причине невидимости этого делать не нужно). Это вообще не тест, а непонимание того, как работает операционная система. К языку и рантайму косяки программиста, использующего их, имеют то отношение, что даже самую отличную программисткую технологию можно закосячить неправильно написанной программулькой.

Для чистого эксперимента нужно что?

Comment: @Softa, остается надеяться, что автор вопроса прочтет и осознает Ваши комментарии.


--

Говорить о том как и что нужно (можно) мерять можно долго. Вот здесь, на ХК есть раздел - "Исследования".

Не хотите там написать? Если остальные подхватят, то может получиться интересная тема.